# Flash On Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash, adobe

Since Adobe recently dropped support for Firefox on Linux, I can't get flash player to work properly on Adobe Connect in Ubuntu. YouTube videos work fine, I only have problems with Adobe Connect.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and Firefox 18.0.1 and Flash 11.2.202.261.

Is there a PPA or another lead I could use to get the latest (or more current) version of Flash Player for Ubuntu?

Comment: haven't you tried installing flash through software center?

Comment: You could maybe download the deb package for Google Chrome, then yank the flash player plugin from that and put it in Mozilla's plugin path? Haven't tried that myself, but I think it could possibly work. There's quite a few results when Googling "chrome firefox flash plugin" and such. Maybe someone who has a more definite procedure can post an answer.

Comment: Flash for Firefox on Linux will only get "security" updates for the foreseeable future. If you need to access sites requiring later versions of Flash, you'll have to use Firefox or any other browser on Windows or use Google Chrome in Linux. I very much doubt the Google Chrome Pepper Flash can be successfully "transplanted" to Firefox.

Comment: @mikewhatever There are several PPAs for Firefox; some are official. But the PPA part of this question is asking for a PPA that provides *Flash*.

Comment: @raminomrani I did download the flash installer from the software center but the version I get from there is not controlling Adobe Connect correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Rambo. I had a similar problem about six months ago, and this is what I found to fix it.

You have two options at this point.

1. Switch to Google Chrome. It now has a built-in version of flash.
2. Check your software installation. A version of flash is available in the ubuntu-restricted-extras package, or kubuntu-restricted-extras, xubuntu-restricted-extras, etc.

The reason Youtube still works is because Youtube has added HTML5 support, which is built in to almost every browser (with the exception of Internet Explorer, which still doesn't fully support it as of version 9 or 10) since around 2009.

The flashplugin-installer package should be all you need, and that is installed with the restricted extras packages.

Please note that downloading and installing the .deb from Adobe does not work unless you move a file to Firefox's directory.

As was stated in the comments, there is no Firefox PPA, because no one needs one. Everything Firefox related that you would ever need is in the Ubuntu repositories or available through a Firefox extension.

The fix I recommend is installing Google Chrome JUST for Adobe connect, so long as Flash works well for everything else on Firefox.

chrome.google.com is the place to find it.

Comment: When you say you had a similar problem, was it with Adobe Connect in Firefox in Ubuntu specifically? I did try Google Chrome but I get as far as I do with Firefox. The problem is (almost certainly) with Adobe Connect since it relies so heavily on the latest version of Flash. Every time they update something in Connect, it breaks what we are doing because we haven't gotten the latest and greatest version of Flash. I already have the flashplugin-installer too. I tried all this before I asked the question. That's why I asked about a PPA for Flash specifically. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah, so... I was using Chromium. Here I am more than six months later and finally I realize Chromium and Chrome are not the same thing. Chrome works beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

1. Open http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
2. Choose tar.gz, download the file
3. Once download is complete, right click on the file (tar.gz) and click on "Extract here"
4. Launch Terminal (Keyboard Shortcut : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>)
5. Go to that location where you extracted the file
6. Run this command : `sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins`
7. Run this command : `sudo cp -r usr/* /usr/`
8. Launch Mozilla Firefox and check that you have Adobe Flash Player

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps out but there is pipelight repo that let you run latest version of flash, shockwave, silverlight, unity player in your native linux browsers such as chromium, firefox, opera. Check it out :
http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html