# Flash Player on Ubuntu 16.04 firefox no video

Tags: firefox, flash

I have ubuntu 16.04, firefox version 47. and according to this page https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html my flash player version is
21.0.0.197.

It was working fine till about a week ago when some updates were installed.  Unfortunately i did not note what they were.

I have no video on firefox.  The sound works fine,  but in the flash box is just a black screen.  I cant even view the settings panel.

I followed the directions here https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html ,  did a purge first,  then installed.  Same issue.  So I tried the install that I found on a few pages.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

No good there also.  Note: Chrome works fine,  its just not working in firefox.

Comment: Are you not able to see *any* youtube videos? Not all of them are flash. In fact, most are supposed to be html5 these days, and firefox has plans to begin next month dropping support for flash altogether.

Comment: Sorry should have noted.  I can see youtube videos on firefox.   But if i visit a page for example https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/  , I see the black box where the video should be.    I can right click on it and get the menu to select global settings,  but that also brings up a black box.

Comment: You could try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/399663/381089

Comment: no go.  I tried the alternate version with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have Flash version 21.0 installed on Ubuntu? I don't think that sounds correct since Adobe has held the Linux version of Flash at version 11.2 for a while now. (Although, [Adobe plans to eventually re-support Linux at version 23.0](https://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2016/08/beta-news-flash-player-npapi-for-linux.html) and beyond.)

Anyways, look at my solution for using Flash on Firefox with Ubuntu 16.04 at [question #799481](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799481/how-to-install-hal-in-16-04lts/827630#827630).

Comment: Instead of only posting a link to another Ask Ubuntu question you should have waited until you have enough reputation to flag this question as duplicate (if it really is) or to add your link in a comment. Alternatively, write a complete answer that contains all important information and does not rely on links, you can add them as reference though.